# Cytoscape.js: add multiple event listeners to node

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cytoscape.js

Using Cytoscape.js, I'd like to have a `mouseover` event associated with a node element, as well as a "click" event. The reason being that on a Desktop browser, `mouseover` is the more user friendly solution, but does not work on touch devices (where the click / tap event works best). I tried the following:

```js
cy.nodes().qtip({
                content: function() {
                  return 'this.data('title') + '</b></a>' +
                      '<br><i>' + this.data('journal') +
                      '</i><br><i>' + this.data('pubDate') + '</i>' +
                      '<br>' + this.data('authors')
                },
                position: {
                  target: 'mouse',
                  adjust: {
                    mouse: false
                  }
                },
                style: {
                  classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
                  tip: {
                    width: 16,
                    height: 8
                  }
                },
                show: {
                    event: 'mouseover',
                    event: 'click'
                },
                hide: {
                    event: 'mouseout',
                    event: 'click'
                }
             });
```

However, only `the last-named listener (in this case "click") is active, whereas the` mouseover does not work.

My question: can I add two listeners to a node? If so, how? If not, how can I achieve to have different events for the Desktop than for the touch device case?

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid JSON.  You can't have duplicate keys.

For `{ foo: 'bar', foo: 'baz' }`, what value is `foo`?  You can't have both, so the browser has to choose one --- the last one, I think.

You're using qtip APIs, not Cytoscape ones.  Refer to the qtip docs: http://qtip2.com/options#show

You need to use space-delimited strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helped me to realise my mistake in defining a value for the same key twice. However, unfortunately it did not solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found an answer using the following two resources:

- http://qtip2.com/options#show (from the answer of @maxkfranz)
- http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/showthread.php?tid=1896

```js
cy.nodes().qtip({
                content: function() {
                  return 'this.data('title') + '</b></a>' +
                      '<br><i>' + this.data('journal') +
                      '</i><br><i>' + this.data('pubDate') + '</i>' +
                      '<br>' + this.data('authors')
                },
                position: {
                  target: 'mouse',
                  adjust: {
                    mouse: false
                  }
                },
                style: {
                  classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
                  tip: {
                    width: 16,
                    height: 8
                  }
                },
                show: {
                    event: 'mouseover tap'
                },
                hide: {
                    event: 'unfocus'
                }
             });
```

Basically multiple events can be defined by separating them with a space (as in the 'show' event) and hide can be done using 'unfocus' for both tap and mouseover.